# Django: If I added new tables to database, how can I query them?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Django: If I added new tables to database, how can I query them?
Do I need to create the relevant models first? Or django creates it by itself?

More specifically,  I installed another django app, it created several database tables in database, and now I want to get some specific data from them? What are the correct approaches? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose another django app has all model files needed to access those tables, you should just try importing those packages and use this app's models.

Answer (score 0):

Django doen't  follow convention over configuration philosophy. you have to explicitly create the backing model for the table and in the meta tell it about the table name...